# MySQL: InnoDB Buffer usage continue growing

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have developed a web application using Laravel and MySQL as my Database with only 14 tables. I have about 3000 user login into the system and do some small transactions. Now I experienced that the InnoDB Buffer usage start at 2% and continnue to grow until about 99,95% and then the application stop to work.

max-Connections = 4000
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 402653184

What else do I need to set/increase to avoid this from happening

Thanks

Comment: The InnoDB Buffer Pool does not increase after server startup, but my colleagues found a memory leak caused by frequent queries against the INFORMATION_SCHEMA (https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=97935)

Comment: Thanks Bill, It seems like this issue has not been resolved yet? Is there something else I can check

Comment: You can check your application code. Does your web app do a lot of queries against the INFORMATION_SCHEMA?

Comment: How much RAM do you have?  What is the value of the STATUS `Max_used_connections`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no query running against the INFORMATION_SCHEMA. Problem was solved by DBA, the inno_buffer_pool_size was set to 2Gb and the inno_pool_instances to 2. This stabilizes and the db is running without any problems